# Continue interrupted tlmgr update

Tags: texlive

I used

```
tlmgr update --all
```

today, and it froze when running mktexlsr, so I aborted it. When I ran it again, it said no updates available. But clearly there remains something to do after updating files. So what commands other than mktexlsr should I invoke to keep TeXLive in order?

Comment: Just as a side-node: I always use `tlmgr update --all --self` so that `tlmgr` updates itself if required. Otherwise it will stop with an error if it need to be updated itself.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Any reason why you don't honor the people who are trying to help with a response?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Because I don't know which one, or any one, is correct. It is long since I have had this question.

Comment: Without any feedback from your side it's useless.

Answer (score 7):

At the end of a run, `tlmgr` takes a number of actions, in the following order:

1. run `mktexlsr`;
2. run `mtxrun --generate` which is the equivalent for ConTeXt, if it is installed;
3. run `updmap-sys` with the proper arguments if necessary (roughly, if font packages got installed/removed);
4. regenerate language files (`language.dat` etc) and run `fmtutil-sys` with the proper arguments if necessary;

So, if `mktexlsr` failed and you had to interrupt `tlmgr`, the following actions have not been taken. Now, *if* you don't use ConTeXt *and* the packages updated didn't require a run of `updmap-sys` nor `fmtutil-sys` then running `mktexlsr` (with sufficient permissions) is enough.

If you want to be sure, you can check in `TEXMFSYSVAR/web2c/tlmgr.log` (where the proper value of `TEXMFSYSVAR` is given by `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFSYSVAR`, usually `/usr/loca/texlive/2011/texmf-var`) the list of recent actions taken by `tlmgr`, eg:

```
[Sun Jul 24 12:49:17 2011] update: xdvi.x86_64-linux (22625 -> 22971)
[Sun Jul 24 12:49:18 2011] update: xdvi (22089 -> 23138)
[Sun Jul 24 12:49:39 2011] update: xetex.x86_64-linux (22625 -> 23143)
```

Then, to be absolutely sure everything's ok, you can reinstall these packages using

```
tlmgr install --reinstall xdvi.x86_64-linux xdvi xetex.x86_64-linux
```

(assuming the previous example was the complete list of updated packages).

Answer (score 3):

that looks okay, because only  `mktexlsr` fails. All updates are successfully installed. Run the command yourself or altenetively `texhash` which is a link on Linux machines

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's the other way round: texhash is a link to mktexlsr. But I don't think it matters at all.